# Git-bash do not uses my enviroment variables for maven installation

Tags: bash, maven, git-bash

I'm trying to run my maven installation locally from the git bash under windows 7.
With the cmd, everything is working but the git bash use allways the javaversion from \system32\java.exe instead of the regular java installtion from \Java\jdk8\bin\java.exe

[image: output from gitbash/cmd]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following into a file named `.bash_profile` into your home folder (like you would on a UNIX system):

```
export M3_HOME=/c/ECG/Maven/mavenCurrent
export JAVA_HOME=/c/ECG/Java/jdk8/jre
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

You may also want to add more environmental variables and path entries this way, depending on what you need to run your system.

Comment: This will fix the problem.
With java -version, the bash still refers to java version 1.7.0 instead of 1.8.0 but the mvn command is now runnig on the bash.

Comment: Maven only cares about `JAVA_HOME`. Try `PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH` (putting your specific Java path first). Then git bash should use the correct Java executable by default. Sorry, I didn't think of already existing `PATH` entries.

Comment: This is part of the output for `env` at git bash:
`/ECG/Maven/mavenCurrent/bin:/c/ECG/Java/jdk8/bin:.:/c/ECG/Java/jdk8/jre/bin`